# How to add currency in opencart?

Tags: opencart

I have add one more currency in currency table of opencart,but it is not reflect on front end.
How would I achieve my goal??

Comment: Please have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

Is the currency "enabled" in the admin panel? Go to the currency you added in admin and see the bottom "status" select field. Disabled there means it will not show on the store front.

Comment: Yes currency which I have added is Disabled. Now Its working .